# Return a dynamically generated pie chart from a servlet and display in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, jfreechart, pie-chart, dynamically-generated

Need your help!

I found this website > http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-return-a-dynamically-generated-pie-chart-from-a-servlet.html

This website show how to generate a pie chart and display in servlet. I managed to display in servlet. However I want to display in JSP instead. I tried looking for the answer. Some said that in JSP, map the img sources to the servlet. I tried but I did not managed to do it.

Below are my codes It would be great if someone help me to display the chart at jsp. I am new to jsp/servlet. Thanks!

at **chart.jsp**

```
<img border="0" src="ChartExample/src/servlet/ChartServlet.java"
    width="100" height="100">
```

at **ChartServlet.java**

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("image/png");

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    JFreeChart chart = getChart();
    int width = 500;
    int height = 350;
    ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(outputStream, chart, width, height);
}

public JFreeChart getChart() {
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();


    Statement stmt = null;
    Connection currentCon = null;


    ChartDao ChartDao = new ChartDao ();
    int chickenrice = ChartDao.CheckChickenRiceRow();
    int currychicken = ChartDao.CheckCurryRiceRow();

    dataset.setValue("Chicken Rice", chickenrice);
    dataset.setValue("Curry Chicken", currychicken);

    boolean legend = true;
    boolean tooltips = false;
    boolean urls = false;

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Orders", dataset, legend, tooltips, urls);

    chart.setBorderPaint(Color.GREEN);
    chart.setBorderStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));
    chart.setBorderVisible(true);

    return chart;
}
```

EDIT:

Servlet is mapped in web.xml is:

```
<servlet> 
   <servlet-name>ChartServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>servlet.ChartServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet> 
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ChartServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/piechart</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You need to specify `servlet-url` at `src` attribute instead of location of Java source file.

Comment: @AVD    so is it like this? <img border="0" src="/piechart"
  width="100" height="100">

Comment: That's true. `<img src='/piechart` alt=''/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test that chart by opening browser with `http://localhost:8080/yourcontext/piechart` url and if everything is OK then use relative-url or absolute-url with `src` attribute of `img` tag.

```
<img src='/piechart' alt='Pie chart'/>
```

Or

```
<img src='http://localhost:8080/yourcontext/piechart' alt='Pie chart'/>
```